# Let $p$ be a prime , then $\{0\} \cup\bigl\{\frac ab \in \mathbb Q : a \ne 0 \space ; (a,b)=1=(p,b) \bigr\}$ is a subring of $(\mathbb Q,+,.)$?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $p$ be a prime , then is the set $\{0\} \cup\Big\{\dfrac ab \in \mathbb Q : a \ne 0 \space ; (a,b)=1=(p,b)  \Big\}$ a subring of $(\mathbb Q,+,.)$?

---

The problem is, how can one show that this is additively closed?

Comment: The rationals with denominator indivisible by $p$? A well-known ring, $\Bbb Q\cap\Bbb Z_p$, the rational $p$-adic integers. You can easily show for yourself that it’s a ring.

Comment: @Lubin: What do you mean by $\mathbb Q \cap \mathbb Z_p$ ?

Comment: this is very straight froward. just use the definition of subring.

Comment: Isn't that the localisation of $\Bbb Z$ at $p$ ?

Comment: @user123733: $\mathbb Z_p$ is $p$-adic integers. but you don't need to worry about those things. *Lubin* just mentioned that it is a well known ring.

Comment: $\Bbb Z_p\subset\Bbb Q_p$. the $p$-adic integers and the $p$-adic numbers are useful to number theorists. You don’t need to know anything about them to answer your question positively.

Comment: @mercio, yes, precisely.

Comment: The $(a,b)=1$ seems strange here.

Comment: @Lubin: this is a classic example why OP should include some of his/her own work/thought in the question.

Comment: @OfirSchnabel: it means that $(p, b) = 1$ whenever $(a, b) =1.$ though it was represented here very poorly.

Comment: Krish, thanks, now it make sense.

Comment: @Krish, I agree entirely. Without such information from OP, we might be led to the unjustified conclusion that OP has given no thought to the question before posting.

Comment: @Lubin ; Krish : I was(am) facing difficulty in showing that it is closed under addition ....

Comment: But the new denominator is the product of the summands’ denominators; product of two numbers indivisible by $p$ is indivisible by $p$. That’s why you need $p$ to be prime.

Comment: @Lubin I would have said $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$, or $\Bbb Z_{<p>}$. OP possibly knows $\Bbb Z_p$ as $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @GPerez, right you are. That’s why I explained what I meant by the notation $\Bbb Z_p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{a}{b} + \dfrac{c}{d} = \dfrac{ad + bc}{bd}.$ Now $(p, b) = 1 = (p, d) \Rightarrow (p, bd) = 1.$ Note that we didn't claim $(ad + bc, bd)= 1.$ If $(ad+bc, bd) \neq 1,$ let $\dfrac{ad + bc}{bd} = \dfrac{r}{s}$ where $(r, s)= 1.$ But $s|bd.$ So $(p, s)= 1.$